# Cost to use VirtualBox by Oracle

Tags: anonymity

What is the cost, if any, to use Virtual Box by Oracle with or through Tor? I have read the Virtual Machines article, the Oracle Terms of Use, the Services Privacy Policy, and the Wiki article link on virtual machines and part of the Wiki article on Virtual Box and have found no information on exact costs to use Virtual Box.

Comment: That's be the same as when using Tor on your host machine.

Comment: ...which would be nothing, given it's open sourced and [dual licensed](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the licensing policy and costs of Virtual Box are outside the topic of Tor's Stackexchange page.

Answer (score 1):

It's free and opensource, except the extension pack : it's free too, but for personal use only. If you're using it for personal needs - just use it, it's totally free. Tor can be a router on a dedicated VM, it's a secure setup, I'm using it myself